# twitter Uri Intent getting null

Tags: android, twitter

could not get Uri when `WebView` redirect to Twitter_Activity

in `LoginButton` Click

```
private void loginToTwitter() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
                pbr =  new ProgressDialog(Twiiter_MainActivity.this);
                pbr.setMessage("Loding..");
                pbr.show();         
                checklogin = false;
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
                    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                    twitter = factory.getInstance();
                     try {
                        requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);                      
                        allReadynew  = true;
                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    // user already logged into twitter                 

                     checklogin = true;
                }
                return null;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    try {                                           
                     if(pbr!=null){
                         pbr.dismiss();
                     }
                     Twiiter_MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();                    
                     }              


            };
        }.execute();
    }
```

Here i m getting Request token and all thing, but when Redirect to `webview` then after login twitter account. getting back to `Activity` and My Below `code` Execute.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        init();
    }


private void init(){

        boolean chkNet = HotSpotSettings.isNetworkAvailable(mcontext);
        if (chkNet == true) {
            // Check if twitter keys are set
            if(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0 || TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0){
                // Internet Connection is not present
                UtilityCommon.showDialogwithTitle(mcontext,"Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!");          
                return;
            }

            if (isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {               
               uri = getIntent().getData();
                    // Here I m getting Null value from Uri

            }           
        }else{
            UtilityCommon.showDialogwithTitle(mcontext, HotSpotSettings.NO_NETWORK);
            return;
        }       
    }
```

`uri` getting `Null` from `Intent` , Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try and rewrite this line:

```
Twiiter_MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
```

To this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, targetActivity.class);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
startActivity(intent);
```

Without seeing the rest of your class, I don't understand why you are calling the `startActivity()` method from `twiiter_MainActivity.this`, since it seems you should be perfectly capable of doing without it.

Comment: still after Wbview Login and get back then uri getting null

Comment: Do you send the intent to be handled in a browser?

Comment: The current Intent, should bring up a window, asking you which app, you want to use to handle your Intent. You therefore can't getIntent, you will need to call the other activity directly with your Intent. Like Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, targetActivity.class).

Comment: No you will need to call it like this.
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, targetActivity.class)
Like I said above.

Comment: but could not match TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL

Comment: Without the callback URL how do you expect to the app to open http://api.twitter.com/ouath to authenticate the user?